# Printing a file

Tags: c, file, io

The goal of this function is to print the contents of a file. Pretty much what the simple invocation of cat does.

Since C is famously hard, I am looking forward to your comments.

```
void showlog(char const * const filename) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(f == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: failed to open file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    const int bufsz = 4000;
    char buffer[bufsz];
    while(1) {
        char* b = fgets(buffer, bufsz, f);
        if(b != buffer) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Is the file always expected to be text or potentially binary data?

Comment: regarding: `printf("ERROR: failed to open file!\n");`   Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  and when the error is indicated by a C library function, should also output (to stderr) the reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The easiest way to do this is call `perror( "your error message" );`

Comment: BTW:  C is not hard.  Now, `prolog` or `modula` or `ada` is hard

Comment: @user3629249 Ada is just annoying

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please don't change or add to the code in your question after you have received answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

From top to bottom without any specific order.

Validate your inputs, if they do not come from user or configuration and you're reasonably sure that they're valid then assert about them. The minimum needed to prevent *random* unexpected behaviours and access violations:

```
assert(filename);
```

To declare preconditions will help future readers to quickly understand them and it's an invaluable help during debugging (also, and especially, together with unit testing when running them in the local machine compiling without `NDEBUG`).

Do not print errors to `stdout`, callers may want to redirect output to something else and you do not want to mixup errors with output (especially because errors won't then visible to the caller...) You can use `perror()` for this:

```
perror("Cannot open file.");
```

However when dealing with shell scripts or a list/batch of inputs it may also be helpful to know which file caused an error (and why):

```
fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file '%s': %s", filename, strerror(errno));
```

Note that `fopen()` sets `errno` to an error code to understand why it failed and `strerror()` converts that numeric error code to a human-readable error message.

Assuming that to read 4000 bytes each time is the optimum is somehow a simplification but you may like to use a *whole* (power of 2) number like 4 KiB. Do not hardcode that magic number inside your function, move outside with a meaningful name (like `DEFAULT_INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE`, just picking one). There are chances you'll need it elsewhere (for command line help or in another I/O function, for example). Simplify your code: `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f)`: if you rename `bufsz` (do it) you'll do it only in one place (even better if you decide to make the size *dynamic* and it's calculated by a function, in this case switch to `malloc()`).

It's not required but it might be helpful during debugging to initialise this buffer to `\0`, if you want to then simply add `= ""` to the declaration. From now on I will assume that you're reading a text file (because of `fgets()` and `"r"`), if it's not true then you should switch to `fread()`.

Expression `b != buffer` is slightly misleading. `fgets()` returns `NULL` when it can't read anything or `str` (its input) otherwise. You can do it this way but it's...unusual. `while (fgets(...))` is much more common.

Technically you know you reached EOF before attempting a new read, you may check `feof()` but I think it's a nano-optimisation you can just ignore. You should, however, check for errors: `fgets()` returns `NULL` also in that case:

```
while (fgets(buffer, bufsz, f)) {
}

if (ferror(f)) {
    perror("Error reading input file...");
}
```

Do not forget that also `fclose()` may fail (for example because buffer is flushed or media is not accessible). Check its return value as we did for `fopen()`.

Note: in real world please do not use `cat` to display a text file content: there are specific commands (which do even more) like `less`, `more`, `tee` and many others.

---

I leave few notes as *exercises* and tips to explore different solutions.

What will happen if your program does not terminate immediately and the input file does not ends with a newline?

Assuming to *process* each chunk (for example to remove blank lines) is `fgets()` the best solution? Consider `getline()` for such cases.

Comment: Do not `puts`. It adds a newline, and the output is not verbatim anymore.

Comment: @vnp right, fixed. Tnx!

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about how to test the cases that you fixed? For example, when might fgets fail?

Comment: Also, considering that there is nothing else I am allowed to do according to the man page, how am I supposed to treat errors when calling fclose?

Comment: Inform user and return proper error code! If something failed then operation has not been completed. Imagine if you `cp` something to your backup disk and it copied only a part of it but you don't know...

Comment: the reasons `fgets()` may fail are...endless. Hardware errors, connectivity (for network drives), running out of memory, access permissions, concurrent accesses (file might be deleted by someone else) or opened without sharing or your program that has a bug somewhere else (and for example overwrite `buffer` pointer with `NULL`, if you're lucky). The point is that I/O may ALWAYS fail and it will find ways to fail that we can't even imagine ;)

Comment: It's the presence of `NDEBUG` that disables asserts, not the absence of `DEBUG` (which has no effect on Standard C functions).

Comment: @TobySpeight thank you, I'm so used to always have them "paired" that I keep forgetting the one to look for is `NDEBUG`

Answer (score 2):

> The goal of this function is to print the contents of a file

What does it take to print everything and nothing else?

#### Do not open in text mode

If the program might be applied to a non-regular text file, OP's use of `fopen(filename, "r")`, `fgets()` and `printf("%s"...)` rely on the reading/writing translation of end-of-line characters to be non-lossy.  While this is  not a common concern, on a machine that expects a `"\r\n"` at the end of each line, input like `"123\n456\r\n789\r"` may not output `"123\n456\r\n789\r"`.  Recommend to use binary mode.

```
// FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
```

Text files that do  not end in a end-of-line can be troubling too.  By going to binary, these text translation issues are moot.

If this approach is taken, code also needs to switch `stdout` to binary mode.

```
FILE *out_file = freopen(stdout, "wb");
```

#### Do not use `fgets()`

There is no requirement to read a *line* at a time.  `fgets()` is a troublesome function to use if the input has *null characters* `'\0'` in it.  On reading with `fgets()`, a *null characters* is not special.  Finding the true length of a buffer that has, say `"abc\0def"` just read into it, is problematic.  As `printf("%s", buffer);` prints only up to that first null character, the `"\0def"` is lost.  Used `fread()/fwrite()`.  This simpler approach likely results in faster I/O too.

```
unsigned char buffer[4096];
size_t in;
while ((in = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, f) > 0) {
  size_t out = fwrite(buffer, 1, in, stdout);
  if (in != out) {
    Handle_Trouble();
  }
}
```

*Null characters* are common in UTF-16 text files.

#### <strike>Use `unsigned char`</strike>

<strike>On exceeding rare machines, `char` contains a trap representation.  Use `unsigned char` for data of uncertain providence.</strike>

---

Of course reading a file with random data may be print nonsense output, but it will be a true echo of the file.  Often when wanting to print text, code will examine the input for non-printable characters and print some alternative text: some sort of data dump, but that is beyond this post.

Comment: I suppose writing in this way does not actually do anything useful if the encoding of the terminal is different from the encoding in the file, right? How would I handle that properly?

Comment: @GregorP.Student Files do not  need an encoding to "print the contents of a file" via cat as code can simply read a character and then print it - and the output is whatever.  Yet to print using a certain encoding on output, your code requirement needs to change from "what the simple invocation of cat does" to "print ASCII" or "print to any discernible UTF encoding."  In such cases, the input stream needs to be characterized (example, see [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and then qualified as it is read.  The output encoding poses limitations, can it print "العربية한국어中文"?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Adriano's answer:

You can replace

```c
printf("%s", buffer);
```

with

```
fputs(buffer, stdout);
```

This avoids all of the excess [backend code](http://blog.hostilefork.com/where-printf-rubber-meets-road/) used for parsing in `printf()`. You could also use `write()`, given your context.

```
write(1, buffer, strlen(b));
```

---

Or, even better, don't use `strlen()` at all and instead use `fread()` and `fwrite()`. Here is my take on this function:

```
#include <error.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 4096

void showlog(char const *const filename) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    size_t nmemb = 0;
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];

    if(!f)
        error(EXIT_FAILURE, 0, "Could not open file");

    while((nmemb = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, f)) > 0)
        fwrite(buffer, 1, nmemb, stdout);

    if(ferror(f))
        error(EXIT_FAILURE, 0, "Error reading file");

    if(fclose(f) == EOF)
        error(EXIT_FAILURE, 0, "Could not close file");
}
```

You could also incorporate chux's suggestion on opening the file in binary mode.

Comment: This is definitely better given the question that I asked but of course eventually I want to do some linewise processing. ;)

Comment: @GregorP.Student Good point, the particular solution you choose to use will depend on how you plan to use this function.

Comment: Remember that `write()`, being POSIX but not Standard C, is less portable than the functions in `<stdio.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
while(1) {
    char* b = fgets(buffer, bufsz, f);
    if(b != buffer) {
        break;
    }
}
```

does not quite do what you want.  Suggest:

```
while( fgets( buffer, bufsz, f) )
{
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Comment: I understand that the second is more idiomatic but it does the same thing, right?

Comment: Code should always be written for ease of readability and understanding.   Code should be written to be neither 'obscure'  nor 'convoluted'.   Employers are strongly against anything that is not crystal clear. This is mostly because many others, besides your self, will be maintaining the code.   If you really want to write 'obscure', etc code, there are several groups, contests, etc for that purpose

Comment: @GregorP.Student It is the same  function, yet less ideomatic.